# Windows and Ubuntu: Can I have Both?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, windows-7

So this is the first time that I'm trying out Ubuntu to get a Tux the penguin plush on TF2 and I'm scared that I might lose Windows 7, my favorite OS. Do I get to keep Windows after installing Ubuntu? Please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you install ubuntu along side of windows you can keep both. But this question is a duplicate.

Use this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

See the following for how to Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot